# WordPress WP_Query showing only first element in the array

Tags: loops, wordpress

I am currently learning on WordPress plugin development and I am trying to build a short code for my plugin 
my plugin is basically a custom post type called property which have 3 meta data boxs in it
price location and date of construction
and one taxonomy called property type which be setted at the backend with  rent or sale
all of this works and if you put them in wordpress they will work 
But my shortcode file does work properly the loop on the WP_Query should return all the post which I have made but instead its returning only the first element found in the WP_Query

Can anyone guide me or fix where I have mistaken please

thanks all

now my short code file name is: properties_post_type_shortcode.php

My plugin file name is: properties_post_type.php

code for properties_post_type_shortcode.php

```
 <?php 

add_shortcode('land_properties',function(){
 $loop = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' =>  'property_post',
            'orderby' => 'title'
            )
    );
    if ($loop->have_posts()){
        $output = '<ul class="land_properties_list">';
        $i=0;

        while( $loop->have_posts() ){
            $loop->the_post();
            $meta=get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'' );
            $output= '
                <li>
                    <a href="'  .get_permalink() . '">
                    ' . get_the_title() . ' | '. 
                    $meta['property_price'][0]. "      " .
                    $meta['property_location'][0].  "      " .
                    $meta['property_date'][0].  "      " .
                    '
                    </a>

                    <div>' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>

                </li>
                ';

            }
  }
                  else {
                  $output="No lands added";
                  }
        //       $loop->wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;

});
```

code for properties_post_type.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: properties_post_type
 * Plugin URI: Have not be set yet
 * Description: this plugin allow you to create custom post type property which you can be modified and edited 
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Muhab Alwan
 * Author URI: https://www.facebook.com/HaaaB
 * License: A "Slug" license name e.g. GPL2
 */
 class PROP_POST_TYPE{
 //default contructor
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->register_post_type();
        $this->taxonomies();
        $this->metaboxes();
    }
    public function register_post_type()
    {
        $args= array(
        'labels' => array(
        'name'=> 'Properties',
        'singular_value' => 'Property',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Property',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Property',
        'edit_items' => 'Edit_Items',
        'new_item' => ' Add New Items',
        'view_item'=> 'View Item',
        'search_items' => 'Search Items',
        'not_found' => 'No Property Found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Property Found In Trash'), 
        'query_var' =>'properties',
        'rewrite' => array(
        'slug' => 'property/'),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 80, // set postion in the backend menu
        'menu_icon' => admin_url(). 'images/media-button-other.gif', // define an image for the prop
        'supports' => array(
        'title',
        //'editor',
        'excerpt',
        //'custom-fields' when we need user to build their own meta box Not required in project
        ) // specify what wordpress types are custom post type support   
        );
        register_post_type('property_post', $args );
    }
    public function taxonomies()
    {
    $taxonomies = array();

    $taxonomies['property_type'] = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'query_var' => 'movie_genere',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'prop/type'
            ),
    'labels' => array(
        'name'=> 'Properties Type',
        'singular_value' => 'Property Type',
        'add_new' => 'Add New Property Type',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Property Type',
        'edit_items' => 'Edit Properties Type',
        'new_item' => ' Add New Properties Type',
        'view_item'=> 'View Property Type',
        'search_items' => 'Search Properties Type',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Properties Type',
        'separate_items_with_comments' => 'Separate Property Type With Comments',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add Or Remove Properties Type',
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose From Most Used Properties Type'
            )
        );
    $this-> register_all_taxonomies($taxonomies); // register all taxonomies build in this plugin 
    }
    public function register_all_taxonomies($taxonomies)
    {
    // foreach is for registering many taxonomy 
    foreach ($taxonomies as $name=> $arr)
        {
        //register ( what the taxonomies name, array of the object type that we register ex post or page 
        register_taxonomy($name,array('property_post'),$arr );
        }
    }
    public function metaboxes()
    {
    // FIRST PRICE META BOX

        add_action('add_meta_boxes', function(){ 
        //css id, title, cb func, page, priority level, call back func argum
        add_meta_box('property_price','Property Price', 'property_price','property_post');
        add_meta_box('property_location','Property Location', 'property_location','property_post');
        add_meta_box('property_date','Date Of Construction', 'property_date','property_post');

        });
        //PRICE PROP
        function property_price($post){
        $price_length = get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_price', true);
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="property_price"> :</label>
        <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+" size="50"  class="widfat" name="property_price" id="property_price" value="<?php echo esc_attr($price_length)?>"  />  </p>
        <?php
        }
        add_action('save_post', function($id){
        if ( isset ($_POST['property_price']))
            {
            update_post_meta(
            $id,'property_price',
            strip_tags($_POST['property_price'])
            );
            }
        });
        // LOCATIO PROP 
    function property_location($post){
        $location_length = get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_location', true);
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="property_location"> :</label>

        <input type="text"    class="widfat"  name="property_location" id="property_location" value="<?php echo esc_attr($location_length)?>"   />  </p>
        <?php
        }
        add_action('save_post', function($id){
        if ( isset ($_POST['property_location']))
            {
            update_post_meta(
            $id,'property_location',
            strip_tags($_POST['property_location'])
            );
            }
        });     
            function property_date($post){
        $dof_length = get_post_meta($post->ID,'property_date', true);
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="property_date"> :</label>
        <input type="date"   class="widfat" name="property_date" id="property_date" value="<?php echo esc_attr($dof_length)?>"  />  </p>
        <?php
        }
        add_action('save_post', function($id){
        if ( isset ($_POST['property_date']))
            {
            update_post_meta(
            $id,'property_date',
            strip_tags($_POST['property_date'])
            );
            }
        });


        //third date of construction metaboxes

    }


}
// initialization essential  to build a cust post
 add_action('init', function(){
  new PROP_POST_TYPE();
  include dirname(__FILE__). '/properties_post_type_shortcode.php';
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

To query all posts, add the following to the args of `WP_Query`:

```
'posts_per_page' => -1
```

Your code:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' =>  'property_post',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
) );
```